# ColdFusion Web Service - Connection refused

Tags: coldfusion, apache-commons, coldfusion-8

I am receiving following error while connecting to ColdFusion web service from client machine

> org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException : Connection refused: connect ( actual link to cfc component )

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check the remote machine's firewall configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Use SOAP UI tool to test the remote web-service. There could be problem with the network / firewall of the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Does the coldfusion web service gzip the content? I recently encountered something similar when we enabled gzip on our server.

If you are doing a CFHTTP call, you need to pass in the following to prevent GZIP:

```
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="accept-encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="te" value="deflate;q=0">
```